# Meaning of this definition of 落雷?

Tags: words

> 落雷:雷が落ちること。**地表物を一つの電極とした**雷雲からの放電現象。[季]夏。

I can't understand the meaning of the bold part.
I looked up 地表物 but could find nothing.

Comment: ~物 means ~のもの. If you imagine lightning, you can understand this sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 地表 = the surface of the ground
- 物 = stuff/objects
- 地表 + 物 = objects on the surface of the ground
- 電極 = electrodes

So the whole thing would be something like,

```
A phenomena of electrical discharge（放電現象）
from a storm cloud（雷雲から）
whereby（とした）
an object on the surface of the ground（地表物）
becomes（とした）
one of the electrodes（一つの電極）
```

Or...

> A phenomenon whereby an object on the surface of the ground becomes one of the electrodes in an electrical discharge from a storm cloud.